Issue with WSO2 API-Manager 4.3.0: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET at localhost:9443
I'm using WSO2 API-Manager 4.3.0 for a project, but I'm running into a problem where the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error appears because the APIM isn't reachable at localhost:9443. On localhost, my backend (.NET Web API) functions perfectly.
Problem
It is not possible to access the WSO2 API-Manager portals using localhost.
Request for Help
I need assistance to make WSO2 API-Manager accessible at localhost:9443 without encountering the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error.
What I've Tried

Windows Network Reset: Attempted to reset the network configuration.
Backend Shutdown: Stopped the .NET Web API backend, but the issue persists.
Browser Check: Tested different browsers, still encountering ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
Hosts File Check: Verified hosts file entries:
127.0.0.1    localhost 
::1          localhost


Ping Test: Successfully pinged localhost:
PS C:\Users\Rayan> ping localhost
Pinging MyCompany [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128


APIM URLs Check: Attempted to access various WSO2 APIM URLs through 127.0.0.1: but the Publisher and Admin aren't working as they redirect to https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize(...) (not functional)
Callback URL Adjustment (To make the publisher and admin portals work perfectly over 127.0.0.1): Adjusted callback URLs in the Carbon portal:
Carbon portal > Service provider list > apim_publisher edit > Inbound authentication config > OAuth/OpenId Edit > changed callback URL to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

This resolved redirects for publisher and admin, but it’s a workaround, not a fix.
Different Device Test: Confirmed functionality on another device (home desktop) over localhost, but unable to replicate on main device.

Additional Information

Operating System: Windows 11
WSO2 API-Manager version: 4.3.0
Browser versions tested: Chrome, Edge, Firefox

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: Tried to change the port used by APIM from 9443, to 10001 by adding this config to deployment.toml and I've confirmed that it's not an issue with the port because the issue is still,
[transport.https.properties]
port = 10001

The issue was with the firewall of my company, as it denied the installation of ssl certificate for wso2.
The solution was by exporting the ssl certificate from my personal device and importing it in my work device certification manager and it worked like a charm!
